# My view block for creating an object doesn't work

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

views.py

```
def create_employee(request):

 if not request.user.is_authenticated():       
     return render(request, 'blazon/login.html')

 else:
     form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
     if form.is_valid():
         employee = form.save(commit=False)
         context = {
             'employee': employee,
             'form': form,
         }
         employee.save()
         return render(request, 'blazon/create_employee.html', context)
         return render(request, 'blazon/employees.html', {'employee': employee})
 return render(request, 'blazon/create_employee.html', {"form": form,})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^create_employee/$', views.create_employee, name='create_employee'),
```

This is my view function for creating new employees in my project. Form gets rendered and when i hit submit the object is populated in database but it does not get redirected to employees.html page.

i have tried using but no luck!

```
return redirect('blazon:employees)
```

instead of the render funtion above. how do i redirect to employees.html page? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to render `create_employee.html` when you're hitting a `GET` request on this view. However, the entire if-else block you've posted here (except the last line) should be executed when you hit the view with a `POST` request.

A few changes you should make:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():       
     return render(request, 'blazon/login.html')
```

else after this is not needed since if the user is not authenticated, you render the above the page. Control exits this function. Just unindent the following lines.

Next,

```
     form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
     if form.is_valid():
         employee = form.save(commit=False)
         context = {
             'employee': employee,
             'form': form,
         }
         employee.save()
         return render(request, 'blazon/employees.html', {'employee': employee})
```

This should not contain `return render(request, 'blazon/create_employee.html', context)` since that is something you want to do when its a `GET` request.

Next, you come out of the `POST` method handling block, and you render the required page.

```
return render(request, 'blazon/create_employee.html', {"form": form,})
```

Comment: some improvement. there's no error anymore but the page gets blank and url still stays at blazon/create_employee.

Comment: If you tried to access the page via web browser, that's exactly what should happen because its a `GET` request. In order to test your `POST` request handler code, you have to submit the data to `create_employee`.
You can test this via your layout or using Postman(https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: I wanted to redirect to the list of employee page where i have list. I'm fairly new to django so i will learn to use postman.

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated(): #checking if user is authnticated
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('blazon:employees') #redirecting after saving the form
    else:
        form = EmployeeForm() #if request is get empty form
    return render(request, 'blazon/create_employee.html', {"form": form,})
```

Comment: sir, Couldn't make it work. Gives out error NoReverseMatch

Comment: if the redirect isn't working that means you should recheck your namespace and name in urls.py file or just share your urls file in here

Comment: i have posted the url i'm using for this function.

Comment: ofc you'll get NoReverseMatch  if you dont have any name space in your main urls.py the redirect would be ('create_employee')

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect to `employees.html` is unreachable because you have another `return` right above it. Just remove it. Change this:

```
return render(request, 'blazon/create_employee.html', context)
return render(request, 'blazon/employees.html', {'employee': employee})
```

to this:

```
# return render(request, 'blazon/create_employee.html', context)
return render(request, 'blazon/employees.html', {'employee': employee})
```